# Without hellfire ring how do I get 45% experience boost?

Tags: diablo-iii

Many says that the level 70 hell fire ring is easier to get. Other said it's much harder than the level 60 hell fire ring.

Well, I have a hard time finding people wanting to do keywarden.

So, how do I get huge xp reward?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau both of the answers on that question are woefully out of date (monster power is ancient history for a start), so it's not currently a good dupe target. I'm also not convinced that it's a dupe at all - both of those answers include Hellfire Rings in them, which this question specifically excludes

Comment: The other items are still all there for the most part, the answers could use to be updated for sure. That the hellfire rings are included is irrevelant as the rest still hold true.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau There are now other rings with bonus XP on them that aren't mentioned at all, although granted they aren't quite as powerful. The danger with both of these questions is that each patch potentially makes existing answers obsolete

Comment: @JonK Yes and we face the same issue with any game that items might change but that still doesn't mean we should have duplicate questions for every patch. I'll set a bounty on the other question to get updated answers which is the best course of action rather than having duplicates.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Fair enough. I guess the question now is what to do with this one until an appropriate answer is posted/edited on the suggested dupe target. I think I will have a read of meta to see if there is an agreed course of action